# Onclick progression bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to get a progress bar to increase on click but whenever I click, the width just jumps to 30%. It's supposed to increase the variable number when I click on the button and the if statements are to check whether if number is equals to 1,2,3 or 4 but I think it's replacing my variable number with 3 straight away.

```js
var number = 0;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  number++;  

  if (number = 1) { 
    elem.style.width = 10 + '%'; 
    elem.innerHTML = 10 + '%';
  }

  if (number = 2) {
    elem.style.width = 20 + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = 20 + '%';
  }

  if (number = 3) {
    elem.style.width = 30 + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = 30 + '%';
  }

  function check() {
    if (number = 4){
      console.log(number);
      document.getElementById('barbutton').className = 'hidden';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>
<div id="myProgress">
 <div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="barbutton" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `(number = 1)` it's like you are defining a variable,

All what you have to do is to put double equals `i.e. (number == 1)` for your conditions also there is no need for the function `check()` you can do it like the others.

```js
var number = 0;

function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
  number++;  

  if (number == 1) { 
    elem.style.width = 10 + '%'; 
    elem.innerHTML = 10 + '%';
  }

  if (number == 2) {
    elem.style.width = 20 + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = 20 + '%';
  }

  if (number == 3) {
    elem.style.width = 30 + '%';
    elem.innerHTML = 30 + '%';
  }

  if (number == 4){
    console.log(number);
    document.getElementById('barbutton').className = 'hidden';
  }
  
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>
<div id="myProgress">
 <div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>
<br>
<button id="barbutton" onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Check [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) for more info about operators.

**Update**

In order to hide the button when `(number == 4)` add this css rule:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Oh!! I get it now, so == is for comparison and = is for defining a variable somewhat? Thank you so much!